# Find the $\frac mn$ if $T=\sin 5°+\sin10°+\sin 15°+\cdots+\sin175°=\tan \frac mn$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, contest-math

It's really embarrassing to be able to doesn't solve this simple-looking trigonometry question.

> $$T=\sin(5^\circ) +\sin(10^\circ) + \sin(15^\circ)  + \cdots +\sin(175^\circ) =\tan \frac mn$$
>
> Find the $\frac mn=?$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integer numbers.

Attepmts:

$$T=2\Big(\sin(5°)+\sin(10°) + \cdots + \sin(85°)\Big) + 1 = 2\Big((\sin(5°) + \cos(5°))+(\sin(10°)+ \cos(10°))+\cdots + (\sin(40°)+\cos(40°))\Big)+1 = 2\Big(\sqrt 2((\sin50°+\sin55°)+\cdots+\sin(80°))\Big)+1.$$

and then I can not see an any way...

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro) to represent the summation as a fraction and continue from there.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1999_AIME_Problems/Problem_11

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly the most elementary approach, but with complex numbers we could write
$$
T = \operatorname{Im}\left(1 + e^{\frac{\pi}{36}i} + e^{2\frac{\pi}{36}i} + \cdots + e^{35\frac{\pi}{36}i}\right) \\
=\operatorname{Im}\left(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + z^{35}\right) \quad \left(z = e^{\frac{\pi}{36}i}\right)\\
= \operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{1 - z^{36}}{1 - z}\right) = \operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{2}{(1 - \cos(5^\circ)) - i\sin(5^\circ)}\right)\\
= \operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{2}{[1 - \cos(5^\circ)]^2 + \sin^2(5^\circ)}[(1 - \cos(5^\circ)) + i\sin(5^\circ)]\right)
\\ = \frac{2 \sin(5^\circ)}{[1 - \cos(5^\circ)]^2 + \sin^2(5^\circ)}
\\ = \frac{2 \sin(5^\circ)}{2 - 2\cos(5^\circ)} = \frac{\sin(5^\circ)}{1 - \cos(5^\circ)}
$$
As the commenter below points out, we have $\displaystyle\frac{\sin x}{1 - \cos x} = \tan\left(90^\circ - \frac{x}{2}\right)$.  It follows that our answer is
$$
\frac{\sin(5^\circ)}{1 - \cos(5^\circ)} = \tan\left(90^\circ - \frac{5^\circ}{2}\right) = \tan(87.5^\circ) = \tan\left(\left[\frac{175}{2}\right]^\circ\right)
$$

Comment: That looks negative.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Found the sign error, fixing now

Comment: $(\sin x)/(1-\cos x)=\cot (x/2)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well, that certainly explains it

Comment: @Beginner you should see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro) linked above.  It looks to me like you were at least trying the right kind of trick

Comment: $T = \operatorname{Im}(1 + e^{\frac{\pi}{36}i} + e^{2\frac{\pi}{36}i} + \cdots + e^{35\frac{\pi}{36}i}) $ shouldn't start with $1$...

Comment: @Andreas why not?  The imaginary part of $1$ is $0$, and $1$ is a convenient starting point

Comment: The first term is $\sin(5)$, so shouldn't the sum start with $e^{\frac{\pi}{36}i} $....?

Comment: @Andreas well, I have added in a zeroeth term of $\sin(0)$

Comment: Yes, works since we are interested in the imaginary part only.

Answer (score 3):

By geometric series,
$$T=\sin 5°+\sin10°+\sin 15°+...+\sin175° = \\
\operatorname{Im} (\sum_{n=1}^{35}\exp(i n 5 \pi/180)) =\\
\operatorname{Im} \exp(i 5 \pi/180) \frac{\exp(i 35 \cdot 5 \pi/180)-1}{\exp(i 5 \pi/180)-1} =\\
\operatorname{Im} \exp(i 5 \pi/180) \exp(i 34 \cdot 5 \pi/360) \frac{\sin( 35 \cdot 5 \pi/360)}{\sin( 5 \pi/360)} =
\\
\operatorname{Im}  \exp(i 36 \cdot 5 \pi/360) \frac{\sin( 35 \cdot 5 \pi/360)}{\sin( 5 \pi/360)}  =
\\ \frac{\sin( 35 \cdot 5 \pi/360)}{\sin( 5 \pi/360)} \\
 $$
and
$$
\arctan(\frac{\sin( 35 \cdot 5 \pi/360)}{\sin( 5 \pi/360)} ) = \\
\arctan(\frac{\sin( 35 \cdot 5 \pi/360)}{\cos(  \frac{\pi}{2}  - 5 \pi/360)} ) = \\
\arctan(\frac{\sin( 35 \cdot 5  \pi/360)}{\cos( 35 \cdot 5 \pi/360)} ) = 
\frac{35 \pi}{72}
$$
or, in degrees, $\frac{35 \cdot 180}{72} =\frac{175}{2} = 87.5 $

Comment: Is there a quick or clever way to compute 
$$
\arctan(\frac{\sin( 35 \cdot 5 \pi/360)}{\sin( 5 \pi/360)} ) = \frac{35 \pi}{72} ?
$$

Comment: Never mind, I see now that the expression in the parentheses can immediately be rewritten as $\sin(87.5^\circ)/\cos(87.5^\circ)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I put it in the main text