# If $\sin 5°+\sin 10°+\sin15°+\cdots+\sin 40°=a$, then $\sin 5°+\sin 10°+\sin15°+\cdots+\sin 175°=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, contest-math

I'm stuck in this question

> If $\sin 5°+\sin 10°+\sin15°+\cdots+\sin 40°=a$
>
> $\sin 5°+\sin 10°+\sin15°+\cdots+\sin 175°=?$

I know that, (I asked before) $\sin 5°+\sin 10°+\sin15°+\cdots+\sin 175°=\tan\frac{175}{2}$

But, I didn't catch a hint here.

Comment: $\sin(\pi/4+x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\sin x+\cos x)$,$\sin(\pi/2+x)=\cos x$,$\sin(3\pi/4+x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\sin x-\cos x)$-These identities may be helpful.

Comment: You can [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059906/find-the-frac-mn-if-t-sin-5-sin10-sin-15-cdots-sin175-tan-frac-mn) to your question more easier than anybody.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
a = \sin 5°+\sin 10°+\sin15°+\cdots+\sin 40°= \\
\operatorname{Im} (\sum_{n=0}^{8}\exp(i n 5 \pi/180)) $$
and
$$
b = \sin 5°+\sin 10°+\sin15°+\cdots+\sin 175°= \\
\operatorname{Im} \left((1 + \exp(i 9\cdot 5 \pi/180)+ \exp(i 2\cdot 9\cdot 5 \pi/180)+ \exp(i 3\cdot9\cdot 5 \pi/180))\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{8}\exp(i n 5 \pi/180)\right) =\\
\operatorname{Im} \left((1 + \exp(i \pi/4)+ \exp(i 2 \pi/4)+ \exp(i 3 \pi/4))\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{8}\exp(i n 5 \pi/180)\right) =\\
\operatorname{Im} \left((1 + i(1 +\sqrt 2))\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{8}\exp(i n 5 \pi/180)\right) =\\
a + (1 +\sqrt 2)\operatorname{Re} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{8}\exp(i n 5 \pi/180)\right) = a + (1 +\sqrt 2)\sum_{n=0}^{8}\cos( n 5 \pi/180)\\
= a + (1 +\sqrt 2)\sum_{n=0}^{8}\sin((90 - 5 n) \pi/180)
$$
Denote $c = \sum_{n=0}^{8}\sin((90 - 5 n) \pi/180)$. Then we have 
$$
b = 2 a + 2c +\frac{2}{\sqrt 2} -1 
$$ 
The last two terms are $\sin 45° = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, $\sin 135° = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. And $\sin 90° = 1$ has to be subtracted because it was counted twice in $2c$.

Solving $$
b = 2 a + 2c +\frac{2}{\sqrt 2} -1 \\
b = a + (1 +\sqrt 2) c
$$

gives $b = \frac{\left( \sqrt{2}+2\right) \, \left( 4 a+\sqrt{2}\right) }{2}$

Comment: (+1) Many thanks. I hope we can complete.

Comment: $\frac{\left( \sqrt{2}+2\right) \, \left( 4 a+\sqrt{2}\right) }{2}$

Comment: @Beginner  I completed that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro),

$2a\cdot\sin2.5^\circ=\cos2.5^\circ-\cos(45^\circ-2.5^\circ)$

$\iff\left(2a+\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)\sin2.5^\circ=\left(1-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)\cos2.5^\circ\  \ \ \   (1)$

If $b=\sin 5^\circ+\sin 10^\circ+\sin15^\circ+\cdots+\sin 175^\circ,$

$2b\cdot\sin2.5^\circ=\cos2.5^\circ-\cos(180^\circ-2.5^\circ)=2\cos2.5^\circ\  \ \ \   (2)$

Divide $(2)$ by $(1)$ to find $$\dfrac{2b}{\left(2a+\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)}=\dfrac2{\left(1-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)}$$ as $\sin2.5^\circ\cdot\cos2.5^\circ\ne0$

Comment: Thank you for answer.