# Prove the trigonometric inequality involving a finite sum.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, summation

Prove that for all real numbers $x$ and any non-negative integer $n,$ we have that $$(1-\cos x) \, |\sin(x)+\sin(2x) +\dotsc +\sin(nx)| \cdot | \cos(x)+\cos(2x)+\dotsc+\cos(nx)| \le 2.$$

Comment: Please provide context. Where did you encounter the problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Use identity for sum sines and cosines in A.P.

Comment: Either use complex numbers or use [Lagrange's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange's_trigonometric_identities).

Comment: Note also that
$$
1 - \cos x = 2 \sin^2(x/2)
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, any source regarding use of complex numbers(in multiplication series)?

Comment: @user675453 see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059906/81360) for instance

Comment: Now I got : $|\sin^2 \frac{nx}{2} \cdot \sin(nx+x) | \le 2. $

Comment: @mmathh uuserr, yup you got it.  Product of two sine function can be atmost 1